# How to add a pause in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, delay, pause

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution. I'm using the console part of developer tools on chrome if that helps :)

I've tried various configurations such as the example below, and all give me an error

```
setTimeout(s)5
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: Create a promise that sets timeout and await it

Comment: This is likely not working because A) You haven't declared `s` as a function, or B) because you typed it exactly as shown above (the code's malformed) instead of `(s)5` you should try `(s, 5000)` (JS handles time in milliseconds, not seconds)... If that doesn't suit your needs, then see my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think you need to pass a function and the length of timeout into the setTimeout method like this example

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: This doesn't pause anything. It just runs later in the event loop.

Comment: thanks i will try!